# How can I put a prop for a function in a component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm in college and we are working with react native. For an assignment, I need to make an interface of a bookshop. I made a title, a shopping cart etc. and below, I've put a book title, the author, a description, ISBN, and a button that says 'read'.

[image]

I want to put all of this (per book) in a component, so I just need to use the component instead of duplicating my code. I know how this works and I use props and everything, but the book title and the button are clickable. Now, is there a possibility to put some kind of prop on the touchable so it knows which function it needs to run?

This is my component now:

```
    const BookTile = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.bookoverview}>
            <Text style={styles.bookauthor}>van {props.author}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.description}>{props.description}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.isbn}>ISBN {props.isbn}</Text>

      </View>
    );
}
export default BookTile;
```

And this is the part in my app file:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => title1()}><Text style={styles.booktitle}>Iene Miene Mutte</Text></TouchableWithoutFeedback>
<BookTile author="M.J. Arlidge" description="Het meisje was..." isbn="978-9-0225-7622-9"/>
      
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="lightgrey" onPress={() => book1()} style={styles.tile}>

<View>
    <Text style={styles.tileText}>GELEZEN</Text>
</View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

So I put my button and my title separatly, so I can use this function when I press them:

```
function book1() {
  console.log("Iene Miene Mutte - GELEZEN");
}

function title1() {
  console.log("Iene Miene Mutte - TITEL GEKLIKT");
}
```

I hope my question is clear. I couldn't find anything on the internet, since I'm a beginner and I don't really understand everything in React. I worked with other JS things before, but this is completely new.

Comment: Rather than having multiple functions, ie: `book1`,`book2`, ... `bookN` and the same with `title`, just create one `book` and one `title` function, and pass data to those as arguments to tell them how to behave.

Comment: you can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65510636/reactjs-pass-multiple-functions-to-child-components-as-a-single-prop

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your question. Nick Parsons answer is correct but if you're still struggling to implement this I have created an example in this Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-surf-y9t4ce?file=/src/App.js

Apologies if I have misunderstood some of the variable names and what the functions are meant to do my (I assume) German? isn't great.

Essentially all I have done is created a couple of functions in your `app.js` and passed them as props to your `bookTile.js` with a couple of parameters to the functions to so we can console log those. This means we can reuse the same function multiple times rather than creating unique functions that do the same thing for every book we might be showing.

For real apps we might get 1000+ books that we want to show so creating things reusable in this way is better than creating thousands of functions.

Feel free to ask any follow up questions from my example - I'm happy to try and answer those.